# convert list of map to map using flatMap

Tags: java, java-8, flatmap

How I can merge `List<Map<String,String>>` to `Map<String,String>` using `flatMap`?

Here's what I've tried:

```
final Map<String, String> result = response
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        s -> (String) s.get("key"),
        s -> (String) s.get("value")));
result
    .entrySet()
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue()));
```

This does not work.

Comment: Can map keys collide, or are they guaranteed unique? If they can collide, what action do you want—take the first one, concatenate them together, maintain a count, what?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Concatenate all keys together, same for value ?

Answer (score 16):

Assuming that there are no conflicting keys in the maps contained in your list, try following:

```
Map<String, String> maps = list.stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: You'll see in my answer: adding a merge function to the `toMap` call avoids the conflicts issue.

Comment: @sprinter, by merge function do you mean the `Set::stream`? It's not needed. If you add duplicate keys in a map the last one overwrites the previous ones.

Comment: no that's not how `toMap` works. From the doc: "If the mapped keys contain duplicates (according to Object.equals(Object)), an IllegalStateException is thrown when the collection operation is performed. If the mapped keys might have duplicates, use toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator) instead." The binary operator I used in my solution is `Map::putAll` which handles the duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

A very simple way would be to just use `putAll`:

```
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
response.forEach(result::putAll);
```

If you particularly want to do this in a single stream operation then use a reduction:

```
response.stream().reduce(HashMap<String, String>::new, Map::putAll);
```

Or if you really want to use `flatMap`:

```
response.stream().map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(Set::stream)
    .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Map::putAll));
```

Note the merging function in the final alternative.

Answer (score 4):

If you're ok with overriding the keys, you can just merge the `Map`s into a single map with `collect`, even without `flatMap`s:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final List<Map<String, String>> cavia = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>() {{
        add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("key1", "value1");
            put("key2", "value2");
            put("key3", "value3");
            put("key4", "value4");
        }});
        add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("key5", "value5");
            put("key6", "value6");
            put("key7", "value7");
            put("key8", "value8");
        }});
        add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("key1", "value1!");
            put("key5", "value5!");
        }});
    }};

    cavia
            .stream()
            .collect(HashMap::new, HashMap::putAll, HashMap::putAll)
            .entrySet()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Will output:

```
key1=value1!
key2=value2
key5=value5!
key6=value6
key3=value3
key4=value4
key7=value7
key8=value8
```